# An expression of size of a plane graph

Tags: graph-theory

I want to express the size $m$ in terms of the order $n$ and $k$-cycle of a plane graph that has for all its interior regions a triangluar boundary but the boundary of the exterior region is a $k$ cycle where $k$ is three or more .

I started with the interior regions the $k=3$ (triangle ) , using Euler identity $n-m+r =2$ ($r$ is the region ) I found that $ 2m=3(r-1)+k$ and then plugging in the identity  but I'm not sure if this is correct because I assumed that it's a maximal planar graph .

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ the the plane graph. Using the assumptions you have, it follows that adding $k-1$ edges to $G$ results in a maximal planar graph (just add all the chords in the exterior cycle that are incident to a given vertex). Thus it follows that $m=3n-6-(k-1)$.